# How to change the height of a view in Constraints Layout?

Tags: android, layout

I am building a calculator UI.

I want to increase the height of the `TextView` to make it look better.

I am using:

- `match_constraint` on all the buttons and
- `TextView` for their `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

Match Constraints makes my UI responsive for different screen sizes and DPIs, but the short TextView just looks ugly.

Plus, I want to change the height of a single button, i.e the = button. I want it to take the space of two buttons.

Comment: Did you try adding padding?

Comment: show your design and whatever you tried for that

Comment: try to use height weight and width weight attribute or else try with a ratio attribute